# How to Enable/Disable app to multi task in Android 7.0 or above Naught?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, split-screen-multitasking

i want to Enable/Disable my app to multi task feature in Android 7.0 or above.
what should i change my menifeast file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Configuring Your App for Multi-Window Mode**

If your app targets API level 24 or higher, you can configure how and whether your app's activities support multi-window display. You can set attributes in your manifest to control both size and layout. A root activity's attribute settings apply to all activities within its task stack. For example, if the root activity has

```
android:resizeableActivity="true/false"
```

set to true, then all activities in the task stack are resizable.

for more detail read [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html)